# Umbraco Razor Orderby custom property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, partial-views

I'm using a partial view in Umbraco v6.2.4 that's pulling a list of related articles. The script below works perfectly and uses the "Refactored.Umbraco.MVCExtensions" to pull out a view count of the articles. So far so good but I would like to order/sort the list of articles by the most popular article i.e. based on the view count. However, the view count is not part of the Umbraco Model so I don't know how to order/sort the list based on this or if there's another way of doing this?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
```

`@using Refactored.UmbracoViewCounter`
`@{`

```
var articles = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(4).Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible()).OrderBy("articleCategory, articleDate desc");

int pagerank = 1;
string elementId;

<div>
    <p class="h3">Most Popular</p>

    @foreach (var item in articles.Take(6))
    {
        elementId = "content_" + pagerank.ToString();
        <div class="items @elementId">
            <span class="pagerank">@pagerank</span>
            <a href="@item.Url">
                <p>@(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("title"))</p>                  
            </a>
            <span class="views-counter"> @ViewCount.GetViewCount(item.Id, category: "articles", increment: false)</span>
        </div>
        pagerank = pagerank + 1;
    }

</div>
```

}

Comment: can you us tell how you have stored your view count?

Comment: The view count is stored in the Umbraco database in a table called "dbo.refViewCount". The table contains id, nodeId, count, lastViewed and category.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to combine both lists and then sort, something like below, I assume you are using petapoco for view count table, I can't test code since I don't have your custom data table but I think you can move to right direction for here:

```
var db = ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext.Database;
var sql = new Sql()
    .Select("*")
    .From<RefViewCount>(new SqlServerSyntaxProvider());

var refViewCountList = db.Query<RefViewCount>(sql);

var articles = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(4).Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible()).Select(r => new {Item = r, ViewCount = refViewCountList.Where(v => v.nodeId == r.Id).Select(v => v.count).SingleOrDefault()}).OrderBy(r => r.ViewCount).ToList();
```

Comment: OK thanks, I have tried this but I get the following error: The type or namespace name 'RefViewCount' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you using Petapoco or entity framework for ViewCount Table? I just assume you had petapoco model called RefViewCount but it should be your real class name of ViewCount table